# Upgrading to New MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Currently I have the MacBook Pro Mid'12 and which comes with a 500 GB HDD I want to upgrade to the 2015 model MacBook Pro. I have cleared my MacBook out so I have now used around 130GB which SSD will I need 256GB or 512GB?

Comment: It's really up to you, and how much storage you think you'll use on the new computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the larger SSD. You'll never be sorry that you have "too much" storage.

Whether you get the 512 GB or the 256 GB, there is currently at least one option for expanding the 2015 MacBook Pro storage: memory that goes into the SD Card slot. Transcend makes a variety of card (different capacities, and different shapes to sit flush with the various MacBook Pros and MacBook Airs). You can use their site to see what would work in the MacBook Pro you are thinking of buying.

Adding an SD card gives you a second volume on the MacBook Pro. It does not "merge" with the built-in storage but you can probably find a way to use it that works for you. Some people use the SD card memory for music, some for photos.

(Technically you *can* combine two physical storage units into a single "logical" unit (that is, one icon on the desktop). It is not what I would recommend here.)

I am not affiliated with Transcend but I have used their products and they work fine.

http://www.transcend-info.com/support/Compatibility

Answer (score 1):

It is your decision and you need to evaluate the circumstances, but keep in mind that you cannot expand the storage. If you see yourself needing a large amount of storage for something like photos or videos, I would recommend the 512. Mine is a 256 and I'm fine with it though.

Answer (score 0):

Physically either of the 256GB or 512GB options will satisfy your requirements as you only have 130GB of data on your old device.

Apple tends to charge more for upgrades than 3rd party options, however there is some value in having an OEM solution to storage. You *could* start with 256GB and use a 3rd party upgrade down the line to obtain more storage if you feel technically inclined enough to do the hard drive swap. It's certainly very simple to do and there are many walkthroughs available on the internet. For instance, [here are the instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27694) for performing this upgrade on a 2014 Retina MacBook Pro. The steps for a more recent generation Retina Macbook Pro would be similar.